# Spring boot Scheduler not working as per configuration

Tags: spring-boot, scheduled-tasks

I have a multi module spring boot application. In one of the modules I have added a class with annotation `@EnableScheduling` and a method with `@Scheduled` annotation(void return type and no arguments).

Now if I do not autowire this scheduler class in any other class, my scheduler method does not get invoked. I checked with `@postinit` method and Scheduler class is getting initialized.

What do I need to do so that Scheduler class alone is enough to run the scheduled methods?

Comment: Can you please share your class? Does it have `@Component` annotation?

Comment: There is another class with EnableScheduling and the scheduler there runs because this class in used in another bean and this might be scanned.

When I add EnableScheduling at main class (SpringBootApplication), already existing scheduler still works, but not the new one. The main class has ComponentScan enabled for the package that has my scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

> Now if I do not autowire this scheduler class in any other class, my scheduler method does not get invoked.

Based on this remark, I would guess that the class you annotated with `@EnableScheduling` lacks the `@Configuration` annotation. See [Annotation Interface EnableScheduling](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/EnableScheduling.html).

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class AppConfig {

    // various @Bean definitions
}
```

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: There is another class with EnableScheduling and the scheduler there runs because this class in used in another bean and this might be scanned.

When I add EnableScheduling at main class (SpringBootApplication), already existing scheduler still works, but not the new one. The main class has ComponentScan enabled for the package that has my scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

I had multiple schedulers in my app. There was no specific threadpool defined for scheduler tasks, so single threaded pool was used. One of the task was failing and stuck in loop and hence my new task was not getting scheduled. When I added below pool, new scheduler started working.

```
@Bean
    public ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler() {
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.setPoolSize(3);
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("ThreadPoolTaskScheduler");
        return threadPoolTaskScheduler;
    }
```